# Prove or disprove: $(\mathbb{Z}^*, \cdot)$ and/or $(\mathbb{Z}^*, \div)$ is a group.

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

I am teaching myself information about groups, but don't really understand how to work through this problem. Here is what I have been thinking so far (please note that I do not need to work through showing any closure):

$\mathbb{Z}^*$ denotes the nonzero integers.
Prove or disprove: $(\mathbb{Z}^*, \cdot)$ and/or $(\mathbb{Z}^*, \div)$ is a group.

> For $(\mathbb{Z}^*, \cdot)$:  Group.
>
> **Associative Law:** Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}^*$. Then $(a\cdot b)\cdot c=a\cdot (b \cdot c)$, and the associative law holds.
>
> **Existence of Identity:** Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}^*$, then $a \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot a = a$, and the identity holds.
>
> **Existence of Inverses:** Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}^*$. Then the inverse of $a^{-1}=-a$, and the inverse holds. Note that this only works because we are ommitting zero.

Hopefully this looks like I am on the right track. I don't know to what extent I can explain logic vs showing it with mathematical operations, so I would appreciate guidance in this respect.

> For $(\mathbb{Z}^*, \div)$: Not a group. Disprove by counterexample.

Yeah, I dunno about this one. I don't think it's true, because we will be introduction rational expressions that won't allow this to hold, but I'm not sure where I can use this information to disprove the statement.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $\cdot$ stands for regular multiplication. In that case, is $-a\cdot a = 1$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I am assuming you're referring to the inverse portion? Of course $-a \cdot a \neq 1$, but I do not know how to show that part of the proof mathematically simply vs. just stating it.

Comment: Okay then think of it this way: if you multiply two integers $a$ and $b$ to get $1$, what most those integers be? Do you see how this answers your question?

Comment: Yeah... I'm a derp. I find the more I start to work on proofs, the more I forget the things I've known about math since forever... thank you.

Comment: It happens! When you're first learning proofs, you start to build very rigid walls up in your mind which trains you how to think. Unfortunately, some things get left outside of those walls so you make small blunders like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inverse under the operation $\cdot$ is the reciprocal.  However most integers have reciprocals that are not integers, hence inverses generally do not exist.

The problem with $\div$ is that closure fails to hold; for most integers $a,b$, $a\div b$ is not an integer.

Comment: Thank you. I probably should have thought about closure, but since the past few problems I have been working on had the reader skip closure, I didn't even think about it. So, just to be clear-- both division and subtraction will not meet the closure property of being a group, correct? Thanks!

Comment: For integers $a,b$, we have $a-b$ again an integer, so closure does hold for the operation $-$.